# Fit according to specific equation using scipy.optimize.curve_fit results in input type error

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am writing a Python Code to plot some data from a CSV file. The plot itself works fine, the problem occurs when I try to fit the data.

I want to fit it according to a specific equation (which you can find in the code) using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. This is the code I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Load data
data = pd.read_csv("file.csv")

# Filter out NaN rows
SP1 = data[data[['SP_B [T]', 'SP_Ic [A]']].notnull().all(1)]

# Data plot
SuperPower1, = plt.plot(SP1['SP_B [T]'], SP1['SP_Ic [A]'],
                        **{'color': 'orangered', 'marker': 'o'})

# Logarithmic axes
plt.semilogx()
plt.semilogy()

plt.show()

# Fit
x = SP1['SP_B [T]']
def law(x, i, a, bo, q, bi):
    return i * (1 + x / bo) ^ (-a) * (1 - x / bi) ^ q

fit = curve_fit(law, SP1['SP_B [T]'], SP1['SP_Ic [A]'],
                bounds=[(0, 0.0, 0.2, 2.0, 0), (2000, 1.0, 2.0, 4.0, 100)])
print(fit)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\file\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 305, in na_logical_op
    result = op(x, y)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_xor' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

As I am quite new to Python, I do not understand what this error message means and would be very grateful for help.

PS: I have tried exchanging the function into a non-exponential one (see below) and got no error, but it does not match my data.
`def law(x, i, a, bo, q, bi): return i * (1 + x / bo) * (-a) * (1 - x / bi) * q`

Update: the fit for the first set of data was fine and worked thanks to Warren's answer, however when I try to fit other data using the same code (see above but with ** instead of ^), the fit does not fit at all:

[image]

My guess is that the boundaries for bi and q allow for a root of a negative number (x is typically from 0 to 10), and this might result in imaginary numbers? However, I do not know if this is the problem and if it is, how to fix it. I could of course make q integer but this would not be in accordance with the physical law. Could anybody help me out again please?

Comment: In Python, to raise `x` to the power `a`, you write `x**a`, not `x^a`.  The `^` operator is the *bitwise exclusive or* operator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! The solution was much simpler than I imagined!